# Display tooltip on cell click agGrid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Is there any way to display default agGrid tooltip after onClick on cell? Cell correctly displays tooltip on mouseenter, but I would like to display tooltip also on mobile view when user clicks on cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it like this:

```
cellClicked(event: CellClickedEvent): void {
    event.event?.target?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseenter', event.event));
}
```

So now, on mobile view, when user click on cell tooltip will be displayed.